# How can I find the common parent of two clusters created from scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram?

Tags: python, scipy, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I have two clusters that are leaves/nodes from a dendrogram created with scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram. I want to find the closest common parent of the two clusters. However, I do not have the cluster indices as indicated by the dendrogram. I have only the individual points that make up each cluster. How can I find the common parent and the number of steps from each of the two clusters to that parent? (Steps meaning the number of generations between the common parent and the cluster in question).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no out-of-the-box way to do it. You will need some boilerplate code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import leaders, ClusterNode, to_tree
from typing import Optional, Tuple, List


def get_node(
    linkage_matrix: np.ndarray,
    clusters_array: np.ndarray,
    cluster_num: int
) -> ClusterNode:
    """
    Returns ClusterNode (the node of the cluster tree) corresponding to the given cluster number.
    :param linkage_matrix: linkage matrix
    :param clusters_array: array of cluster numbers for each point
    :param cluster_num: id of cluster for which we want to get ClusterNode
    :return: ClusterNode corresponding to the given cluster number
    """
    L, M = leaders(linkage_matrix, clusters_array)
    idx = L[M == cluster_num]
    tree = to_tree(linkage_matrix)
    result = search_for_node(tree, idx)
    assert result
    return result


def search_for_node(
    cur_node: Optional[ClusterNode],
    target: int
) -> Optional[ClusterNode]:
    """
    Searches for the node with the given id of the cluster in the given subtree.
    :param cur_node: root of the cluster subtree to search for target node
    :param target: id of the target node (cluster)
    :return: ClusterNode with the given id if it exists in the subtree, None otherwise
    """
    if cur_node is None:
        return False
    if cur_node.get_id() == target:
        return cur_node
    left = search_for_node(cur_node.get_left(), target)
    if left:
        return left
    return search_for_node(cur_node.get_right(), target)


def get_LCA(
        node_1: ClusterNode,
        node_2: ClusterNode,
        root: ClusterNode
) -> ClusterNode:
    """
    Returns the lowest common ancestor of the given ClusterNodes in the subtree of root.
    :param node_1: ClusterNode
    :param node_2: ClusterNode
    :param root: ClusterNode - root of the subtree
    :return: the lowest common ancestor of the given ClusterNodes in the subtree of root
    """
    if not root:
        return root
    left = get_LCA(node_1, node_2, root.get_left())
    right = get_LCA(node_1, node_2, root.get_right())
    if root.get_id() == node_1.get_id() or root.get_id() == node_2.get_id():
        return root
    if left and right:
        return root
    if left:
        return left
    if right:
        return right


def get_num_steps(
    ancestor_node: ClusterNode,
    descendant_node: ClusterNode
) -> Optional[int]:
    """
    Returns number of steps from the ancestor node to the descendant node.
    :param ancestor_node: ClusterNode - ancestor node
    :param descendant_node: ClusterNode - descendant node
    :return: number of steps from the ancestor node to the descendant node or None if the 
    descendant node is not a descendant of the ancestor node
    """
    if ancestor_node is None or descendant_node is None:
        return None
    if ancestor_node.get_id() == descendant_node.get_id():
        return 0
    left = get_num_steps(ancestor_node.get_left(), descendant_node)
    if left is not None:
        return left + 1
    right = get_num_steps(ancestor_node.get_right(), descendant_node)
    if right is not None:
        return right + 1
    return None


def get_leaves_ids(node: ClusterNode) -> List[int]:
    """
    Returns ids of all samples (leaf nodes) that belong to the given ClusterNode (belong to the node's subtree).
    :param node: ClusterNode for which we want to get ids of samples
    :return: list of ids of samples that belong to the given ClusterNode
    """
    res = []

    def dfs(cur: Optional[ClusterNode]):
        if cur is None:
            return
        if cur.is_leaf():
            res.append(cur.get_id())
            return
        dfs(cur.get_left())
        dfs(cur.get_right())
    dfs(node)
    return res
```

Here is an example of usage of these hepler functions to get the ancestor of two clusters:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as shc
import numpy as np
data = make_blobs(centers=10, cluster_std=0.9, n_samples=3000, random_state=0)
lkage = shc.linkage(data[0], method='ward')
# For cluster_ids we are using n_clusters=n_samples.
# However any number of cluster works here
cluster_ids = shc.fcluster(lkage, t=data[0].shape[0], criterion='maxclust')

# Change seed to take other random clusters
seed = 3
np.random.seed(3)
# Take two random cluster_ids
cluster_id_1, cluster_id_2 = np.random.randint(cluster_ids.min(), cluster_ids.max(), size=(2))
ancestor = get_LCA(
    node_1=get_node(lkage, cluster_ids, cluster_id_1),
    node_2=get_node(lkage, cluster_ids, cluster_id_2),
    root=shc.to_tree(lkage)
)
```

Distance:

```
get_num_steps(ancestor, get_node(lkage, cluster_ids, cluster_id_1))
```

You can visualize the results using following code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
# Set initial_clusters_dot_size to 1 if initial clusters contain many dots
initial_clusters_dot_size = 50
color = np.zeros(shape=(data[0].shape[0]))
color[get_leaves_ids(ancestor)] = 3
color[cluster_ids==cluster_id_1] = 1
color[cluster_ids==cluster_id_2] = 2
sizes = np.ones(shape=(data[0].shape[0]))
sizes[cluster_ids==cluster_id_1] = initial_clusters_dot_size
sizes[cluster_ids==cluster_id_2] = initial_clusters_dot_size
plt.scatter(data[0][:,0], data[0][:,1], s=sizes, c=color)
```